# Node kill thread but not process

Tags: node.js, multithreading, terminate

I was wondering if you could terminate just the thread on which the node application is executing but NOT the process.

Now, I know this sounds strange, because node IS single-threaded, BUT I'm working on an .NET application that hosts node in-process. And when I terminate node with `process.exit()` the whole application gets closed, which is a behavior I don't want. I just want the node thread to get terminated.

Honestly I'm so desperate I even tried, getting a list of all application threads prior to creating the thread on which node is executing, and then another list after it's created, then removing all threads that were present prior to starting node, keeping a reference to the remaining thread, thinking it was the node thread. As you could expect this did not turn out so well.

I'm using EdgeJS to host node, if that makes any difference. It does not have a built in functionality to terminate itself, unfortunately.

Oh and `server.close()` doesn't work for me, for some reason.

I'm hosting a video streaming server in my node code, if that info can help you in any way.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: The reason why you "trick" did not work is that it looks like you're running your node.js in-process. That is, not in a thread at all. Therefore there's exactly zero thread that's running node.js apart from your .NET application.

Comment: The EdgeJS library (that's in .NET), creates a separate thread just to run the node code inside of it.

Comment: Are you sure? I took a quick look at the docs and don't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I used a simple method to test this. I started a new thread in managed code that just executes my .net code which starts EdgeJS and executes the node.js code. I closed that thread and my node server was still alive. So I think there must be a new thread in play, since that's the only way that could happen. Not 100% sure, but pretty sure it's a new thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node thread needs to co-operate by clearing everything that is running on the event loop and then it terminates naturally by returning. So just stop listening for requests, close handles etc. You can use `process._getActiveRequests` and `process._getActiveHandles` to see what is keeping the event loop alive.

You can also abruptly interrupt the node thread just by calling OS apis but this will leak a lot of garbage until you exit the process so you cannot start/restart node a lot of times before you need to exit the process anyway to free the leaked resources.

Comment: I've tried closing the thread via OS APIs, but can't pinpoint/reference the thread. Any documentation on `process._getActiveRequests()` and `process._getActiveHandles()`, since they don't seem to be in the official api documentation?